# Найти и удалить самый большой файл через командную строку (.bat)

Tags: windows, cmd, bat, ос

Надо найти в указанной папке самый большой файл и предложить его удаление. Всё к чему я дошёл, это нахождение этого самого файла через dir /o, но как предложить удалить именно первый файл мне неизвестно.

Comment: Если средствами Windows Batch: 1. Найти первый в списке файл вывода команды **DIR /O-S** с помощью цикличного парсера **FOR /F**. 2. Тут же его удалить с прерыванием цикла.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для консоли команда будет выглядеть так:

```
dir /a-d/b/o-s | (set /p #= &for /f "tokens=1,* delims==" %i in ('set #') do @del /f/q "%~j")
```

Теперь по шагам.

```
dir /a-d/b/o-s
```

Исключает из обработки папки `/a-d`, сортирует от более емкого файла к меньшему `/o-s`, в конечном выводе отображает только имя файла `/b`.
Далее данные передаются по конвейеру, где

```
set /p #=
```

устанавливает переменную `#`, значением которой является имя искомого файла. Выражение

```
for /f "tokens=1,* delims==" %i in ('set #') do @del /f/q "%~j"
```

извлекает имя файла из созданной переменной (первый токен равен `#`, второй - имени файла, который, к слову, может содержать пробелы). Ну, а `del`, как несложно догадаться, удаляет файл.
В случае если команда переносится в бат-файл, знак процента перед переменными вроде `%i` удваивается, то есть должен быть `%%i`.
Чем хорош описанный выше метод? Не нужно прерывать цикл, так как нужный нам файл "уходит" направо сразу по окончанию работы `dir`, а вот минус такого подхода - к созданным через конвейер переменным мы можем обратиться только через `set` причем только в контексте скопа конвейера (о чем говорят скобки). Еще одним положительным моментом такого подхода является простота восприятия команды: видно, что сперва выполняется команда `dir` с определенными установками, а после полученные данные обрабатываются в конвейере.
Более мощные средства манипуляции файлами предоставляет PowerShell, задача на котором решается так:

```
ri (gci | ? {!$_.PSIsContainer} | sort length)[-1]
```